# Need suggestions for screen recording softwares, alternatives to ShareX

Tags: screen-recording, audio-recording, video-recording

Need suggestions for free screen recording software.
I have been using ShareX for a long time. It's pretty good. But I must manually select
whether to record the microphone or system sound. And it only records one of those.
I couldn't find a way to record the system and microphone sound together.
Also, there seems to be no support where one could email and find some answers.

Any good software which works as well as ShareX?